# Looking for web hosting in the UK

Tags: hosting

I'm trying to change from webhostuk to another UK hosting plan.

The service must have:

- Cpanel
- does not disable any features in the php.ini file
- unlimited addon domains
- unlimited databases
- linux based
- PHP and MySQL

I have tried a few but they don't provide all the features on shared hosting.

Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the php.ini stuff, but I've had very good experiences with [Express Hosting](http://express-hosting.co.uk). Their Business package gives you everything you need, it's on Linux and comes with SSH access. I've found it to be fast and reliable, and their support is good.

Answer (score 0):

Try Cymru Wales Hosting

[Cymru Wales Hosting](http://chostwales.com/). They are very flexible. I sit accross from the owner and they seem to know their stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try [VooServers](http://www.vooservers.com/).

Many people I know moved to these guys when another hosting company went under - and they've been exceptionally helpful. They have everything you seem to need described!

Answer (score 0):

Put a request in the 'request for products and services' section at

[www.webhostchat.co.uk](http://www.webhostchat.co.uk/)

You should get quite a few responses from hosts who can do exactly what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason you want to stick with cpanel? www.34sp.com are great, been using them for years, they use plesk for site management.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if they're located in the UK (and I know for sure they don't use CPanel -- they've developed their own system), but you should try out Dreamhost. I've been using them for four months and I've had no complaints; the staff is very helpful, the pricing is good, and the support is nice.

Also, they have an API for their control panel, which is very useful.

Comment: They are NOT in UK, but in US (have a look at http://www.dreamhost.com/contact.html). In US there are hundreds of good quality hosting providers. In Uk it's harder to find a good one.